# build out each page or draw from db

Tags: .net

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I am building a stock website with about 60 stocks that I will be tracking. Each stock page will have a profile and with some basic details like pe ratio, volume, 52 week high/low, etc. I will be changing a lot of stuff day to day because the stock market changes day to day with new headlines, price, etc. I want to be able to update each one kind of how yahoo finance does it. The other thing is I will be giving my opinion on each stock on a day to day basis.
My question is should I build out each view separately with the details or should I dynamically build each view from the database.
I'm pretty sure I should do it dynamically, I am just not sure how I would go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, definitely dynamic; remember the DRY principle!
Your design should have a action which takes a stock symbol.

```
public ActionResult Stock(string id)
```

And in this action you should read the stock symbol from the url and new up the viewmodel and send that to your view to display the required data.

To make it clean you can setup route constraints so that your URL looks very clear -

http://example.com/stock/MSFT

http://example.com/stock/GOOG